# How to make reaction when all checkboxInputs are unselected?

Tags: r, shiny

Look: when ya click the checkbox the notification in the bottom left corner appears. The shiny sees the action when ya select checkbox or unselect when the second one is selected... but Shiny doesn't see the moment when ya unselect the last checkbox!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("ccc", "ccc", choices = c("choice1", "choice2"), selected = c("choice1", "choice2"))
)

server <- function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$ccc, {
    showNotification("clicked!", type = "default")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for `observe` as `observeEvent` already has a feature called `ignoreNULL` so just add that to it. By default that value is set to `TRUE`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("ccc", "ccc", choices = c("choice1", "choice2"), selected = c("choice1", "choice2"))
)

server <- function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$ccc, {
    showNotification("clicked!", type = "default")
  },ignoreNULL = F)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unselecting all the object generate a `NULL` for the object `input$ccc`.
To be able to catch the event of unselecting all the object you have to change your `observeEvent` to an `observe` like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput("ccc", "ccc", choices = c("choice1", "choice2"), selected = c("choice1", "choice2"))
)

server <- function(input, output){
    observe({
        input$ccc
        showNotification("clicked!", type = "default")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```